# htaccess redirect to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying to figure out a way to redirect only one domain to HTTPS but haven't found a good solution. I was able to redirect all requests to https by using the HTTPS!=on condition but I host multiple domains and only one has SSL.

This gave me some success.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(127\.0\.0\.1|localhost)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to redirect URLs like www.mydomain.com/order/ and mydomain.com/order/

Basically it works only for the main page currently at www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(127\.0\.0\.1|localhost)$
```

That says, "Only use the next `RewriteRule` if the host is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, *exactly*." If you host `mydomain.com` on that same server, it won't match. You need to add the name of the domain you want to redirect.  Example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That worked a treat. I went a slightly different route in the end though. I ended up using RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.domain\.com|domain\.com)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]